# Twitter Trends API - org.json.JSONException (Android)

Tags: java, android, json, api, twitter

I am trying to fetch Twitter trends but getting JSONException. Searched other similar topics and tried the possible ways but still getting the same exception. I am new to JSON, consuming an API . Probably, I am missing sth simple but just can't see it. Hope, you help me to see it. Thanks in advance.

As Twitter API [says](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place) "The response is an array of “trend” objects that encode the name of the trending topic...". So, I am trying to get the response as a JSONArray of JSONObjects (trends)..

In the log, I see, I get status code 200. That's what I get :

```
D/Authorization Class: GET response code: 200
D/Authorization Class: JSON response: [{"trends":[{"name":"#\u0627\u0644\u0627\u062A\u062D\u0627\u062F_\u0627\u0644\u0647\u0644\u0627\u0644","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%84","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%84","tweet_volume":null},{"name":"#KohLanta","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23KohLanta","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23KohLanta","tweet_volume":13188},{"name":"Anthony Weiner","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22Anthony+Weiner%22","promoted_content":null,"query":"%22Anthony+Weiner%22","tweet_volume":39739},{"name":"#mitamtour","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23mitamtour","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23mitamtour","tweet_volume":21580},{"name":"#HistoriasTerrorEn4Palabras","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23HistoriasTerrorEn4Palabras","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23HistoriasTerrorEn4Palabras","tweet_volume":15852},{"name":"#YoTrabajoPorLapatria","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23YoTrabajoPorLapatria","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23YoTrabajoPorLapatria","tweet_volume":75066},{"name":"Milagro Sala","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22Milagro+Sala%22","promoted_content":null,"query":"%22Milagro+Sala%22","tweet_volume":18934},{"name":"Drake and Taylor Swift","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22Drake+and+Taylor+Swift%22","promoted_content":null,"query":"%22Drake+and+Taylor+Swift%22","tweet_volume":47344},{"name":"Cenk Tosun","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22Cenk+Tosun%22","promoted_content":null,"query":"%22Cenk+Tosun%22","tweet_volume":null},{"name":"FOCO BELIEBERS","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22FOCO+BELIEBERS%22","promoted_content":null,"query":"%22FOCO+BELIEBERS%22","tweet_volume":59554},{"name":"\u062E\u0627\u0644\u062F \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0645\u064A\u0631\u064A","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%8A%22","promoted_content":null,"query":"%22%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%8A%22","tweet_volume":null},{"name":"Ergin Ataman","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22Ergin+Ataman%22","promoted_content":null,"query":"%22Ergin+Ataman%22","tweet_volume":null},{"name":"#LOSCPSG","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23LOSCPSG","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23LOSCPSG","tweet_volume":12447},{"name":"#NationalChocolateDay","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23NationalChocolateDay","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23NationalChocolateDay","tweet_volume":71011},{"name":"#T\u00DCRK\u00FCnBayram\u013129Ekim","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23T%C3%9CRK%C3%BCnBayram%C4%B129Ekim","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23T%C3%9CRK%C3%BCnBayram%C4%B129Ekim","tweet_volume":37252},{"name":"#art\u0131kbenimsin","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23art%C4%B1kbenimsin","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23art%C4%B1kbenimsin","tweet_volume":73324},{"name":"#BakeOffItalia","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23BakeOffItalia","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23BakeOffItalia","tweet_volume":null},{"name":"#\u0632\u062F_\u0631\u0635\u064A\u062F\u0643_13","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23%D8%B2%D8%AF_%D8%B1%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%83_13","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23%D8%B2%D8%AF_%D8%B1%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%83_13","tweet_volume":20390},{"name":"#ReisBedelliAskerlik\u0130stiyoruz","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23ReisBedelliAskerlik%C4%B0stiyoruz","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23ReisBedelliAskerlik%C4%B0stiyoruz","tweet_volume":15625},{"name":"#ViihTubeVoltaProUtero","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23ViihTubeVoltaProUtero","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23ViihTubeVoltaProUtero","tweet_volume":91304},{"name":"#tvoh","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23tvoh","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23tvoh","tweet_volume":null},{"name":"#ThatsMyGirlProjectTODAY","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23ThatsMyGirlProjectTODAY","promoted_conte<code>
```

Error line is :

```
E/Authorization Class: GET Error : org.json.JSONException: Value [{"as_of":"2016-10-28T19:57:52Z","trends":[{"query":"%23%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%84","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%84","tweet_volume":null,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#الاتحاد_الهلال"},{"query":"%23KohLanta","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23KohLanta","tweet_volume":13188,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#KohLanta"},{"query":"%22Anthony+Weiner%22","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22Anthony+Weiner%22","tweet_volume":39739,"promoted_content":null,"name":"Anthony Weiner"},{"query":"%23mitamtour","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23mitamtour","tweet_volume":21580,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#mitamtour"},{"query":"%23HistoriasTerrorEn4Palabras","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23HistoriasTerrorEn4Palabras","tweet_volume":15852,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#HistoriasTerrorEn4Palabras"},{"query":"%23YoTrabajoPorLapatria","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23YoTrabajoPorLapatria","tweet_volume":75066,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#YoTrabajoPorLapatria"},{"query":"%22Milagro+Sala%22","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22Milagro+Sala%22","tweet_volume":18934,"promoted_content":null,"name":"Milagro Sala"},{"query":"%22Drake+and+Taylor+Swift%22","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22Drake+and+Taylor+Swift%22","tweet_volume":47344,"promoted_content":null,"name":"Drake and Taylor Swift"},{"query":"%22Cenk+Tosun%22","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22Cenk+Tosun%22","tweet_volume":null,"promoted_content":null,"name":"Cenk Tosun"},{"query":"%22FOCO+BELIEBERS%22","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22FOCO+BELIEBERS%22","tweet_volume":59554,"promoted_content":null,"name":"FOCO BELIEBERS"},{"query":"%22%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%8A%22","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B1%D9%8A%22","tweet_volume":null,"promoted_content":null,"name":"خالد السميري"},{"query":"%22Ergin+Ataman%22","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22Ergin+Ataman%22","tweet_volume":null,"promoted_content":null,"name":"Ergin Ataman"},{"query":"%23LOSCPSG","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23LOSCPSG","tweet_volume":12447,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#LOSCPSG"},{"query":"%23NationalChocolateDay","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23NationalChocolateDay","tweet_volume":71011,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#NationalChocolateDay"},{"query":"%23T%C3%9CRK%C3%BCnBayram%C4%B129Ekim","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23T%C3%9CRK%C3%BCnBayram%C4%B129Ekim","tweet_volume":37252,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#TÜRKünBayramı29Ekim"},{"query":"%23art%C4%B1kbenimsin","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23art%C4%B1kbenimsin","tweet_volume":73324,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#artıkbenimsin"},{"query":"%23BakeOffItalia","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23BakeOffItalia","tweet_volume":null,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#BakeOffItalia"},{"query":"%23%D8%B2%D8%AF_%D8%B1%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%83_13","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23%D8%B2%D8%AF_%D8%B1%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%AF%D9%83_13","tweet_volume":20390,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#زد_رصيدك_13"},{"query":"%23ReisBedelliAskerlik%C4%B0stiyoruz","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23ReisBedelliAskerlik%C4%B0stiyoruz","tweet_volume":15625,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#ReisBedelliAskerlikİstiyoruz"},{"query":"%23ViihTubeVoltaProUtero","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23ViihTubeVoltaProUtero","tweet_volume":91304,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#ViihTubeVoltaProUtero"},{"query":"%23tvoh","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23tvoh","tweet_volume":null,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#tvoh"},{"query":"%23ThatsMyGirlProjectTODAY","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23ThatsMyGirlProjectTODAY","tweet_volume":51622,"promoted_content":null,"name":"#ThatsMyGirlProjectTODAY"},{"query":"%23BuenV
```

Related code block is :

```
                while ((metin = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuilder.append(metin);
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "GET response code: " + String.valueOf(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()));
        Log.d(TAG, "JSON response: " + stringBuilder.toString());

        String response = stringBuilder.toString();

        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("trends");
        JSONObject jsonObj;


        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
           // jsonSonuc =(JsonObject) jsonDizi.get(i);
            Trend trend = new Trend();

            jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            trend.set_trendQuery(jsonObj.getString("query"));
            trend.set_trendURL(jsonObj.getString("url"));                
            trend.set_trendName(jsonObj.getString("name"));

            trends.add(i,trend);
        }
   }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "GET Error : " + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
    finally {
        if (httpURLConnection != null)
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
```

Calling the method in MainActivity in an AsyncTask:

```
     public class BringTheTrendsTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, ArrayList<Trend>> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        /*progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading..!");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();*/
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Trend> doInBackground(Object... param) {
        if(NetworkControl.haveConnection(MainActivity.this))
            return Authorization.getTrends();
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Trend> trends){
    /*
        progressDialog.dismiss();
   */
        if(trends.isEmpty())
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ArrayList-Trend blank",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        else
            FillTheListView(trends);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pointed out that the JSON data you receive was something like : `[{"trends": ....}]`

It's a `JSONArray` containing a `JSONObject` that has the `trends` array :

you did :

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("trends");
```

but it should be something like :

```
JSONArray  jsonData = new JSONArray(response);
JSONObject jsonResponse = jsonData.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("trends");
```

Moreover, it's best to use [Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Overview) to parse that kind of JSON data defined by a specific schema

Comment: While typing my answer, you asnwered it :) You are exactly right. Thank you very much. I will accept it.

Edit : Unfortunately, i cant vote up as of the moment .

Comment: I am getting 50 trends as a response. In Twitter API it says this will return 10 trends only. Do you have an idea about this ? Tested it on Apigee Twitter API Console and it returns 50 trends there too.

Comment: other people seem to have this problem see https://twittercommunity.com/t/more-than-10-results-in-trends-place-json-endpoint/57432

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after thinking on it step by step again, I guess, I fixed it. It may help someone.

First of all, below is a sample response from Trend API:

```
    [  
       {  
        "as_of":"2016-08-24T23:25:43Z",
        "created_at":"2016-08-24T23:24:14Z",
        "locations":[  ],
        "trends":[  ]
       }
   ]
```

As we see, the response itself is already a JSONArray. We go inside this array by calling jsonArray.getJSONObject(0). By doing this we reach to:

```
    {  
        "as_of":"2016-08-24T23:25:43Z",
        "created_at":"2016-08-24T23:24:14Z",
        "locations":[  ],
        "trends":[  ]
    }
```

So, it's a JSONObject now. We want trends array inside that JSONObject. So, we get it as _jsonObject.getJSONArray("trends") and assign this to a JSONArray.
And then inside a for loop, we can reach to inner values.